# How to turn off ".\" in powershell when execute local command?

Tags: powershell

By default Powershell requires ".\" before any local executable. So to execute local command in Powershell you need type something like

```
.\foo arg1
```

How to turn requirement to type ".\" off, so I can run just like

```
foo arg1
```

And what is the correct name of the ".\"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.`is the current directory and `\`is the path separator. That means `.\foo` is the relative path to the foo program.

If `.`is not included in your `PATH` environment variable, you have to specify it as above. To avoid that, you could add `.` to your `PATH` variable. But as a rule of thumb, never do so, since it leads to security risks. Better use `.\foo` or even better provide the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, actually I know that this could lead to security issue (somebody can place malitious executable to your local folder). However I do not really think this could be large problem for my local environmant. Let me check.

Answer (score 1):

It is a security feature to make sure you run only the executables at the desired location. This ensures that you are running the right executable and not a hijacked one.

This is a language / shell implementation and you cannot turn it off, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

you can't turn it off, however you could turn your could put your functions in a module (or even a script you load somewhere else), and load that then at least calling those functions looks nicer (without the .\foo

Answer (score 0):

perhaps . isn't in the path, the tabcompletion function detect that, so if you write foo[TAB] then automatically is expanded to .\foo.  For this reason i don't see where is the "extra work" putting the dot and the slash if tabcompletions takes care of that.